# how to extract a list from a linked list in c++

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm trying to implement those two functions "extract" and "deleteList" and I somehow can't get my head around it.
I know how a linked-list works but I'm new to programming and just can't figure out an algorithm. Could I ask for some tips?

I want the extract function to return a list of values that fulfill the predicate and remove those from the original list (thats why its passed as a reference).

I want the delete function to delete all those that are the same as those passed from the argument

My code looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
struct Node
{
    T data;
    Node* next;
};
template <typename T>
void showList(const Node<T>* head)
{
    while(head->next != NULL)
        {
            cout<<head->data<<" ";
            head = head->next;
        }
    cout<<endl;
}

template <typename T>
Node<T>* arrayToList(const T tab[], size_t size)
{
    Node<T> *prev;
    for(int i = size-1; i>=0 ; i--){
        Node<T> *p = new Node<T>;
        p->data = tab[i];
        p->next = prev;
        prev = p;
    }
    return prev;
}

template<typename T>
Node<T>* extract(Node<T>*& head, bool (*predicate)(const T&))
{

}

template <typename T>
void deleteList(Node<T>*& head)
{
    //delete passed in
}

bool isEven(const int& n)
{
    return n%2 == 0;
}
bool isLong(const string& s)
{
    return s.size() >=5;
}
```

Thank you guys!

Comment: For starters, its `while (head)`, not `while (head->next)`

Comment: Also, in your arrayToList function, pointer prev is not initialized and you assign p->next to prev.

Comment: The function `deleteList(Node<T>*& head)` shouldn't be that difficult. Just save the `next` pointer, `delete head`, and set `head=saved_next` while header is non-null.

Comment: The question for extract is more than a SO question, it's a query to do you work. Without adequate environment you will go quick to the wrong direction. In general you must keep in mind that you have to change the *predecessor* of the list item that matches the condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, your `showList()` has a potential problem with dereferencing
a null pointer. So it should look like this:

```
template <typename T>
void showList(const Node<T>* head)
{
    while(head != NULL)
    {
        cout << head->data << " ";
        head = head->next;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Secondly, it is more convenient to have auxiliary functions like
`pushToList()` and `popFromList()`:

```
template <typename T>
void pushToList(Node<T>*& head, const T &element)
{
    Node<T> *p = new Node<T>;
    p->data = element;
    p->next = head;
    head = p;
}

template <typename T>
T popFromList(Node<T>*& head)
{
    T value;

    if (head != NULL) {
        Node<T>* tmp = head;
        value = head->data;
        head = head->next;
        delete tmp;
    }

    return value;
}
```

You can rewrite your `arrayToList()` using `pushToList()`:

```
template <typename T>
Node<T>* arrayToList(const T tab[], size_t size)
{
    Node<T>* head = NULL;
    for(int i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        pushToList(head, tab[i]);
    }
    return head;
}
```

And implement `deleteList()` using `popFromList()`:

```
template <typename T>
void deleteList(Node<T>*& head)
{
    while (head != NULL) {
        popFromList(head);
    }
}
```

`exctract()` also can be implemented in terms of push and pop. You
just create two temporary lists and push to them according to the
predicate:

```
template<typename T>
Node<T>* extract(Node<T>*& head, bool (*predicate)(const T&))
{
    Node<T> *extracted = NULL;
    Node<T> *rest = NULL;

    while (head != NULL) {
        T value = popFromList(head);
        if (predicate(value)) {
            pushToList(extracted, value);
        } else {
            pushToList(rest, value);
        }
    }

    reverseList(extracted);
    reverseList(rest);

    head = rest;

    return extracted;
}
```

One problem is after the main work the temporary lists are
reversed. So we need the `reverseList()` function, which can be also
implemented in terms of push and pop:

```
template <typename T>
void reverseList(Node<T>*& head)
{
    Node<T> *result = NULL;
    while(head != NULL) {
        pushToList(result, popFromList(head));
    }
    head = result;
}
```

It is not a very effective implementation but I think it does the work.

I've put the complete source code [here](https://gist.github.com/rexim/8078996).